# $n=n_1+\cdots +n_r>0$. Use Lagrange's Theorem to show that $\prod_{i=1}^r (n_i!)\mid n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer and partitioned into $n=n_1+\cdots +n_r$.

To make use of the Lagrange's theorem, somehow I need to build a group whose order is $n!$ and has elements of order $n_1!,\ n_2!,\cdots,\ n_r!$. But I don't see how to do that. Any hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: Multinomial coefficient works. Do you need to do using Lagrange?

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, I was told to use it specifically. And I'm not familiar with multinomial.

Comment: Embed $S_{n_1}\times\cdots\times S_{n_r}$ in $S_n$.

Comment: To elaborate just a bit on this, you don't need a group of order $n!$ with an element that has this order.  It's just as good to find a subgroup that has the required order.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @LordSharktheUnknown for using Lagrange to prove it.

Comment: How to embed $S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_r}$ to $S_n$? Does one simply use Cayley's Theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partition $X= \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ into $X= X_1 \cup \cdots \cup X_r$ such that $X_k$ has $n_k$ elements. This is possible exactly because $n=n_1+\cdots +n_r$. The permutations of $X$ that leave each $X_k$ invariant form a subgroup of $S_n$. This subgroup is isomorphic to $S_{n_1} \times \cdots \times S_{n_r}$ and so has order $n_1! \cdots n_r!$.